# I am try to make file organizer using python. but when I run the program error is showing. I supposed that is come from mp3 files

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, operating-system

This is my code,

```
import os
import shutil
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

root=Tk()
root.title('File Organizer')
filelocation=""
files=''
image_foramt=['png','jpg','jpeg']
video_format=['avi','wmv','gif','mp4','mkv']
audio_foramt=['mp3']
text_format=['txt','pdf','docx']

def goto_path():
    global filelocation
    filelocation =filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir='c:/', title='select path')
    path=Label(text=filelocation)
    path.pack()
    proccess_btn = Button(root, text="Manage my files")
    proccess_btn.bind("<Button-1>",proccess)
    proccess_btn.pack()

def proccess(event):
    files = os.listdir(filelocation)
    label_filenames = Label(text=files)
    label_filenames.pack()
    files_count=len(files)

    progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=files_count, mode='determinate')
    progress_bar.pack()

    for file in files:
        exet = file.split('.')[-1].lower()
        print(exet)
        if exet in image_foramt:
            if "images" in files:
                file = replacement(file, filelocation, "images")
                shutil.move(f'{filelocation}/{file}', f'{file}/images')
            else:
                os.mkdir(f'{filelocation}/images', )
                shutil.move(f'{filelocation}/{file}', f'{file}/images')

        elif exet in video_format:
            if "videos" in files:
                file = replacement(file, filelocation, "videos")
                shutil.move(f'{filelocation}/{file}', f'{file}/videos')
            else:
                os.mkdir(f'{filelocation}/videos')
                shutil.move(f'{filelocation}/{file}', f'{filelocation}/videos/{file}')

        elif exet in audio_foramt:
            if "audios" in files:
                file = replacement(file, filelocation, "audios")
                shutil.move(f'{filelocation}/{file}', f'{file}/audios')
            else:
                os.mkdir(f'{filelocation}/audios')
                shutil.move(f'{filelocation}/{file}', f'{filelocation}/audios/{file}')

        elif exet in text_format:
            if "books" in files:
                file=replacement(file,filelocation,"books")
                shutil.move(f'{filelocation}/{file}', f'{file}/books')
            else:
                os.mkdir(f'{filelocation}/books')
                shutil.move(f'{filelocation}/{file}', f'{filelocation}/books/{file}')
        progress_bar['value']+=1
        root.update_idletasks()
        progress_label.config(text=progress_bar)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    label_complete=Label(text="complete")
    label_complete.pack()
    print("complete")

    def replacement(file,file_loc,folder):
        location=f'{file_loc}/{folder}'
        files = os.listdir(location)
        if file in files:
            # Path
            path = os.replace(file, location)
            return path
        else:
            pass
            # renamed the file f.txt to d.txt
            print("File %s is renamed successfully" % file)
    
    path_btn=Button(text="path", command=goto_path)
    path_btn.pack()
    print(path_btn)
    progress_label=Label(root,text="")
    progress_label.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    print(filelocation)
```

I using Tkinter to create gui. When I run the programm error is shownig

---

> *Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1892, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "F:\Programming Languages\Python\file_organizer\main.py", line 43, in proccess
> file = replacement(file, filelocation, "images")   File "F:\Programming Languages\Python\file_organizer\main.py", line 90, in
> replacement
> path = os.replace(file, location) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'AlbumArtSmall.jpg' ->
> 'C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/images'**

**

My folder hasn't file which name 'AlbumArtSmall.jpg'
how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your code tries to replace a file with a folder. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: When a file already exists in that folder, I want to replace that file like the normal process of the move file to another place.

Comment: This is file organizer. So when I give to the path which I want to manage. It automatically identifies the file extension and chose what folder should add it. In some cases already that folder exists and also inside the folder that file already exists so that  time I want to replace or skip it. like normal file movement.. I using the file variable inside of the replacement function. The parameter is file so no issue comes from it. am I right?

Comment: Are you sure that all parent folders of the destination exist?

Comment: Yeah. audios, videos, images, books folders are already exist.

Comment: You're using a relative path because the `file` is only the filename without its folder. You could try combining it with its source location.

Comment: location=f'{file_loc}/{folder}' I supposed you said this one.

Comment: I mean the first parameter `os.replace` only contains the filename without its directory

Comment: ah ok, now permission error showing.  PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/images/AlbumArtSmall.jpg' -> 'C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/images'

Comment: @JanWilamowski I solve those issues.. Thank you for your guidance.